# Stack overflow while working with CFBuilder plugin

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

In the past 30 minutes of working in CFBuilder (I have it as an Eclipse Plug in), I got this error 4 times:

```
A stack overflow has occurred. 
You are recommended to exit the workbench. 
Subsequent errors may happen and may terminate the workbench without warning. 
See the .log file for more details. 
Do you want to exit workbench?.
```

together with:

```
Unhandled event loop exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

The log file had this:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2010-05-11 09:41:51.951
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
 at com.adobe.ide.cfml.parser.generated.CFMLParserBase.getVariableInfo(CFMLParserBase.java:1613)
 at com.adobe.ide.cfml.parser.generated.CFMLParserBase.getVariableInfo(CFMLParserBase.java:1603)
 at com.adobe.ide.editor.model.CFMLDOMUtils.getVariable(CFMLDOMUtils.java:2375)
 at com.adobe.ide.editor.model.CFMLDOMUtils.getComponentNameFromNode(CFMLDOMUtils.java:2484)
 at com.adobe.ide.editor.model.CFMLDOMUtils.getComponentNameFromFunctionCall(CFMLDOMUtils.java:2168)
 at com.adobe.ide.editor.model.CFMLDOMUtils.getComponentNameFromNode(CFMLDOMUtils.java:2495)
 at com.adobe.ide.editor.model.CFMLDOMUtils.getComponentNameFromFunctionCall(CFMLDOMUtils.java:2168)
 at com.adobe.ide.editor.model.CFMLDOMUtils.getComponentNameFromNode(CFMLDOMUtils.java:2495)
 at com.adobe.ide.editor.model.CFMLDOMUtils.getComponentNameFromFunctionCall(CFMLDOMUtils.java:2168)
 (and so on - repeat n times)
```

It happens whenever I copy/paste something. Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this is a CFB bug http://forums.adobe.com/thread/551761

EDIT: i saw now you added comment there ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please see Update 1 to ColdFusion Builder, this should fix the issue being reported here:
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/846/cpsid_84607.html